# Fill a boolean array with List that contains indices that must be true

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have `List<int> NullValuesIds` containing indices.

How can I initialize a boolean array assigning `true` to the indices that are from `NullValuesIds`, and using LINQ? (The boolean array size is known like size 100).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int maxIndex = NullValuesIds.Max(); // or some other maximum

var boolArray =
   Enumerable
   .Range(0, maxIndex)
   .Select(NullValuesIds.Contains)
   .ToArray();
```

If performance is important, this would be much faster if `NullValuesIds` was a `HashSet<int>`.

Comment: I liked this answer because you passed `Contains` as an argument and made the compiler do some work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple(and efficient):

```
List<int> NullValuesIds = new List<int>{1, 3, 7};
bool[] arr = new bool[100]; // all are false since a bool is a value type with default value == false
NullValuesIds.ForEach(val => arr[val] = true);
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but `List<T>.ForEach` is not technically LINQ. 8)

Comment: It's true that they aren't under the same namespace, but when most people say "LINQ" they mean "lambada expr."

Comment: I don't know if that's true (I doubt it actually), but even if that were true, that doesn't mean we should start interpreting LINQ to mean lambda. They are different terms that mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

You could **sort** and use `BinarySearch`:

```
var values = NullValueIds.OrderBy(id => id).Distinct().ToList();
var boolArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                          .Select(index => values.BinarySearch(index) >= 0)
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) `Select` overload:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,100)
             .Select((n, index) => NullValuesIds.Contains(index) ? true : false)
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: There's no reason to use the indexed `Select` when the source data are already a zero-based sequence of consecutive integers... `n` and `index` will always be equal...

Comment: Wouldn't index be equal to n in every itteration???? I think index is too much and n would suffice.